# Iap purchase - trial without auto renewable subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I want to implement trial option but with omitting the payments. I don’t want to use auto subscription feature with trial because it forces user to pay after trial period. I just want to let the user decide after trial period - is it ok for Apple to handle trial by myself without making IAP?

Comment: Yes, locally(in your app) you can handle trial period. After end of trail you can go for IAP. But if you want to handle this with trail period in IAP service. then user will have to pay after trail period otherwise he can cancel service before.

Comment: Yes I guess I’ll handle it locally - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In app purchases can be successfully tested with sandbox environment even for subscriptions without doing any payment.

Check the URL to know about the duration of different test duration times in  [sandbox environment from Apple](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d)

Comment: I was not asking for testing the iap. The question was about the implementation of trial period without subscription.